# Looking to standardize all variables except one using dplyr in R - object not found

Tags: r, dplyr

EDIT: This question is now obsolete with `across()` and the `rlang` panoply of tools.

I'm using the flights data set from the nycflights13 package as an example of an issue I'm running into. I'm looking to standardize a bunch of variables except one (in the case of the code below, the variable "year").

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

flights2 <- flights %>% mutate_each_(funs(scale), -year)

Error in has_names(vars) : object 'year' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Follow-up question, what do I do if I don't want to standardize multiple variables, such as "year", "month", and "day"?

Comment: The order of your arguments looks wrong. Try this:  `flights %>% mutate_at(vars(-year, -time_hour, -dest, -origin, -tailnum, -carrier), funs(scale))` (those extra dropped variables are character strings). More generally, you can use `mutate_if` with an appropriate predicate function

Comment: To the error: see `?summarise_each`: "For standard evaluation versions (ending in _) these [the vars argument] can be either a list of expressions or a character vector."
So you could e.g. do `flights %>%  mutate_each_(funs(scale), setdiff("year", names(flights)))`. Which leads to the next error (`scale` needs numeric values). 
You probably want `flights %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)` or `flights %>% mutate_at(vars(-year, -month, -day), scale)`

Comment: Thanks @Chrisss and @lukeA - `mutate_at()` works perfectly. Feel free to use your comments as answers and I'll upvote.